# Posting data that is not in a form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP, so please pardon me for anything stupid.

I'm creating a phonebook (as my first PHP project) with the ability to `delete` an entry from the database.
Here's my code:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($entries); $i++) { ?>
    <tr <?php echo ($i % 2) ? "class='alt'" : ""; ?>>
        <td><?php echo "0" . $entries[$i]["id"] . "."; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $entries[$i]["name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "+92" . $entries[$i]["number"]; ?></td>
        <td>
            <form action="delete.php" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" id="delete">
            </form>
        </td>
     </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Question: How do I "POST" the ID (`$entires[i$]["id"]`) to `delete.php`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [hidden input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) to post the id.

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="id"/>
```

Just put the form around your `<table />` and add the hidden input to the `<td />` that already contains the id.

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($entries); $i++) { ?>
    <tr <?php echo ($i % 2) ? "class='alt'" : ""; ?>>
        <td><?php echo "0" . $entries[$i]["id"] . "."; ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $entries[$i]["id"];?>" />
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $entries[$i]["name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "+92" . $entries[$i]["number"]; ?></td>
        <td>
           <input type="submit" value="Delete" id="delete">
        </td>
     </tr>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="<?php $entires[i$]["id"] ?>" name="id">`

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Yet another addition to my PHP experience-library.